# ksh while loop is behaving weird

Tags: bash, ksh

I have the while loop in ksh which reads the file and loop through each line. 
Here is the same file contents (TestCases.txt)

```
TEST_PROC_1(1)/TEST_1,TEST_2,TEST_3/N/P
TEST_PROC_1(1)/TEST_1,TEST_2,TEST_3/N/N
TEST_PROC_2('CICD_DEMO.txt')/TEST_1,TEST_2,TEST_3/N/N
TEST_FUNC_1(100)/TEST_1,TEST_2,TEST_3/N/P
TEST_FUNC_2/TEST_1,TEST_2,TEST_3/N/N
TEST_PROC_4/TEST_1,TEST_2/N/N
TEST_FUNC_3(3)//N/P
```

The scripts which reads the document

```
swd=$(pwd)
export swd

file=${swd}/TestCases.txt

export testCaseIndex=1
export validateTblIndex=1

cat ${file} | while IFS=\/ read procname tablelist hold_data testcase_type
do
    echo "$procname $tablelist $hold_data $testcase_type"

    ksh ${swd}/assets/sh/main.sh "${procname}" "${tablelist}" "${hold_data}" "${testcase_type}" "${testCaseIndex}" "${validateTblIndex}"
    ret=$?
    echo $ret
    (( testCaseIndex+=1 ))
    (( validateTblIndex+=1 ))
done
```

Here is the problem

If I comment the ksh call it iterates till last line.

```
TEST_PROC_1(1) TEST_1,TEST_2,TEST_3 N P
0
TEST_PROC_1(1) TEST_1,TEST_2,TEST_3 N N
0
TEST_PROC_2('CICD_DEMO.txt') TEST_1,TEST_2,TEST_3 N N
0
TEST_FUNC_1(100) TEST_1,TEST_2,TEST_3 N P
0
TEST_FUNC_2 TEST_1,TEST_2,TEST_3 N N
0
TEST_PROC_4 TEST_1,TEST_2 N N
0
TEST_FUNC_3(3)  N P
0
```

If I uncomment it stops with first line of the file.

```
TEST_PROC_1(1) TEST_1,TEST_2,TEST_3 N P
0
```

Kindly help out what could be possible issues. ksh call works fine even I run separately. 
I have ksh93 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main.sh` is also reading from standard input, which it inherits from the loop, so it is consuming data meant for the `read` command. Given that this surprises you, you may simply be able to redirect the script's standard input from `/dev/null`.

(Also, unless `cat ${file}` is just filling in for some other process that produces the data, use input redirection instead of a pipe.)

```
while IFS=/ read procname tablelist hold_data testcase_type
do
    echo "$procname $tablelist $hold_data $testcase_type"

    ksh ${swd}/assets/sh/main.sh "${procname}" \
       "${tablelist}" "${hold_data}" "${testcase_type}" \
       "${testCaseIndex}" "${validateTblIndex}" < /dev/null
    ret=$?
    echo $ret
    (( testCaseIndex+=1 ))
    (( validateTblIndex+=1 ))
done < $file
```

If `main.sh` *does* need to read from standard input, use a different file descriptor for `read` command.

```
while IFS=/ read procname tablelist hold_data testcase_type <&3
do
    echo "$procname $tablelist $hold_data $testcase_type"

    ksh ${swd}/assets/sh/main.sh "${procname}" \
       "${tablelist}" "${hold_data}" "${testcase_type}" \
       "${testCaseIndex}" "${validateTblIndex}" < /dev/null
    ret=$?
    echo $ret
    (( testCaseIndex+=1 ))
    (( validateTblIndex+=1 ))
done 3< $file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked and also thanks for nice explanation.